# Does $\sin(n)$ hit all real numbers between $-1$ and $1$ if $n$ is an integer?

Tags: trigonometry, real-numbers, integers

More concisely, is this statement true:
$$\forall\; y \in \left(\left[-1, 1\right] \subset \mathbb R\right) \;\exists\; n \in \mathbb N \;\vert \sin n = y$$
At first I thought that since $\sin$ is $2\pi$-periodic, and $\pi$ is irrational, that the answer would be yes, but I'm not so sure... I'm not really sure how to work with the constraint that $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: No, the interval $[-1,1]$ is uncountable.  (If you don't know what that means, look it up.)

Comment: However $\{\sin(n)\mid n\in\mathbf N\}$ is *dense* in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Bernard How do you prove that?

Comment: @DanielEscudero It's equivalent to the irrationality of $\pi$.

Comment: It is linked to the fact that a subgroup of $\mathbf  R$ is either discrete or dense; hence a subgroup of $\mathbf  R:2\pi\mathbf Z$ is either finite (since $\mathbf R/2\pi\mathbf Z$ is compact) or dense.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\sin x = 1$.

The solutions to this are of the form $\left({\dfrac {\pi}2+ 2\pi\cdot n}\right)$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$, which aren't integers.

Comment: Or indeed any rational number apart from $0$.

Comment: @Joffan Sure, but I only needed one counterexample.